# The firebase flutter array cannot be searched

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mobile

The firebase flutter array cannot be searched

Please help, I haven't found a solution for several days of searching.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection("Chats")
   .where("members", arrayContains: "90TDhef6G9QY7ljJyZjdpeaLNoA3")
   .where("members", arrayContains: "yutgffvvpobjjJyZjdpeaLNoA3")
   .get();
```

I want to search for a chat that contains users.

This error message appears:

> You cannot use 'array-contains' filters more than once.

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? Is there an error message? If there is no error, but you're not getting the documents from this query that you expect, can you show a screenshot of one of thosee documents?

Comment: this error message appears => ( '!hasArrayContains': You cannot use 'array-contains' filters more than once.)

Comment: That's correct: Firestore queries can only contain a single `arrayContains`. See the limitations on a Firestore query here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message and documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) say, a Firestore query can only contain a single `arrayContains` operator. On your current data structure, your only option is to perform one `arrayContains` check in the query, and then filter the rest of it in your application code.

To allow the query to completely run on the databae, consider storing the members in a map field rather than in an array:

```
membersMap: {
  '90TDhef6G9QY7ljJyZjdpeaLNoA3': true, 
  'yutgffvvpobjjJyZjdpeaLNoA3': true
}
```

With this structure, you can use a `==` comparison to find a match, and having multiple such equality checks *is* allowed in a query:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection("Chats")
   .where("membersMap.90TDhef6G9QY7ljJyZjdpeaLNoA3", isEqualTo: true)
   .where("membersMap.yutgffvvpobjjJyZjdpeaLNoA3", isEqualTo: true)
   .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myCollection').where('myArray', arrayContains: 'searchTerm').get().then((querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
    print(doc.data());
  });
});
```

in this querying the "myCollection" collection and searching for documents where the "myArray" field contains the search term "searchTerm". The arrayContains operator is used to search for items in the array.